# Inapp purchase restoring consumable products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

i have uploaded an application which doesnot have webservices, in my application there is an option for user to buy a coin (consumable) using inapp purchases and use these coins to unlock new level. today apple rejected the application and send me following note:

**

> Your app uses intermediary currency (coins) to purchase items that
>   function as non-consumable products (unlocking levels) but does not
>   include a restore mechanism.  Users restore transactions to maintain
>   access to content that they’ve already purchased.Please modify your
>   app to include an optional user registration feature that allows users
>   to restore their purchases to all of their iOS devices.  We recommend
>   indicating that account registration is necessary to restore
>   previously purchased In-App Purchase products, and providing a way for
>   users to register later if they wish to access this content in the
>   future.

**

how can i fix this, as mentioned earlier i dont have a webserver and i cannot use webservices, is there any way around to fix this and get application uploaded.

Comment: You should not normally use consumables to unlock levels. This is what apple documentation recommend to do. You should make this inapp as a non-consumable, so the user could restore those unlocked levels when he moves to another device, for example. Restoring non-consumables requires no webservices since it is done by apple already. So this would be a fast fix.

Comment: Or use iCloud perhaps

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this?

Comment: yes. i use parse as backend and store data over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i fixed it by adding login screen in the application and storing user Object in parse.com and when i use inapp purchase i store coins count on Parse and retrieving it on application startup. thanks everyone.